# Consuming a Nodejs Webservice via C# Client

Tags: c#, node.js, web-services, post

I have a webservice, written in nodejs and developing a c# client. I do not have any problem with GET method but have problem with POST.

Here is my client code

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 request.Method = methodType.ToString();

 UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
 {
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(content);
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
       dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
  }

   request.ContentType = "application/json";

   try
   {
     using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
   {
     using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
      {
         var  result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
      }    
    return response;
    }    
 }
 .....
```

and here is my server code

```
router.post('/api/activation/activate', urlencodedParser, (req, res, next) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        (async function () {

            try {
                routerAppFeature.Delete(req.body.type.toUpperCase(), req.body.id);
                console.log(req.body.HardwareId);
                console.log(req.params.HardwareId)
                console.log(req.query.HardwareId);
                var result = { "data": "Okay :)" + req.body.HardwareId, "errorCode": "-1" };

                res.json(result);

            } catch (error) {

                console.log('!!Error in activate method: ' + error);
                return reject(error);
            }
        })();

    }).catch(error => {

        var err = { "message": error.message, "errorCode": "1" };
        res.json(err);
    });
});
```

so my problem is that

after execution of **using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())**

my post method is fired and req.body is empty because I do not pass any params before firing the method..

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Seems like you are not included any body parsers for express. Have you installed `body-parser` or any other modules that helps with parsing post requests

Comment: thank you for the reply @JanithKasun but its not true.. if you like my server code there method's param is urlencodedParser, that means I used body-parser.. the problem is that, before i passing the data, it fires..

Comment: GET requests use url encoding to pass parameters, using  urlencodedParser does not mean you are using body-parser.

Comment: @JanithKasun I am using const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
and I do not want to do that with GET.. so looking for a solution with post.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you require and configure body-parser as a middleware

Comment: @JanithKasun there is no extra thing.. var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false});
 only this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.. I still do not know what actually problem is but the code below, is working..

```
public void Test(string content)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
     try
     {
        var res = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:4000/api/activation/activate",
            new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

       res.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       Console.WriteLine("Response " + res.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result +
       Environment.NewLine);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
     }
   }
 }
```

so it is nothing to do with nodejs, but c# side.